# Reverse multiplication with unknown dx - solve for original AX after multiple mul/add constant steps

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, lcg

I have this repeating iterative process in 16-bit x86 asm

```
rec_loop:
  mul bx          ; constant value of 0x11bf
  add ax, 0x4743
  loop rec_loop
```

it's running several times but for our case let's say it runs 3 times, now after it is finished I get `dx:ax` and need to recover the initial `ax` of this program (the initial `dx` is 0).
From first sight, we can see that information about dx is being lost in this process because `mul` override the last `dx` with a new one.

I'm looking for a way to reverse this process if it's even possible, of course with the assumption the code above can't be changed.

If I forgot to explain something or didn't give enough details about the problem just tell me and I'll answer.

Comment: The low word determines the high word. If you know `ax` you know `dx`.

Comment: This looks like some sort of simple PRNG of the multiplicative congruential kind. x = (a * old_x + c) mod m --> old_x = a_inverse * (x - c) mod m. One can use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to find a_inverse. This is probably covered by previous questions on Stackoverflow somewhere.

Comment: If these mul/add constants are chosen to give [the LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) a period of 2^16, that means any given AX value can only have been produced by one previous AX value.  Otherwise there are some value that converge, i.e. some AX values could have come from any of a few previous values.  But only one of those values will be part of the cycle that the LCG produces before repeating any values.  (The DX value would differentiate, but that only goes back one step, since its not an input to `mul`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation x<sub>n+1</sub> := (a * x<sub>n</sub> + c) mod m, with a = `0x11bf`, c = `0x4743`, m= 2<sup>16</sup> forms a pseudo-random number generator. Specifically, a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with period 2<sup>11</sup>. So clearly not a high-quality PRNG, but it may be sufficient for use cases that merely require data that looks kind of random. I note that the question does not state the context in which this code is used.

The sequence of x<sub>i</sub> (here successively generated in `AX`) can be reversed by using the modular multiplicative inverse a<sub>inverse</sub> like so: x<sub>n-1</sub> = a<sub>inverse</sub>* (x<sub>n</sub> - c) mod m. In this case the modular multiplicative inverse is `0xde3f`.

Note that the value of `DX` is not needed in the backwards computation, and at any point in the sequence can readily be determined from `AX` if needed. The determination of the multiplicative inverse below uses a *naive* method based on the definition. For larger operand sizes this is hugely inefficient, one would want to use the Extended Euclidean algorithm instead.

Simple C99 code for experimenting with the computation of the multiplicative inverse and the reversing of the sequence of values in `AX`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define X_0   (0xc001)
#define ITERS (3)

uint32_t modular_inverse (uint32_t a, uint32_t m)
{
    for (uint32_t x = 1; x < m; x++) {
        if (((a % m) * (x % m)) % m == 1) {
            return x;
        }
    }
    printf ("no inverse found\n");
    return 0;
}

uint16_t umul16_lo (uint16_t a, uint16_t b)
{
    return (uint16_t)(a * b);
}

uint16_t umul16_hi (uint16_t a, uint16_t b)
{
    return (uint16_t)(((uint32_t)a * b) >> 16);
}

int main (void)
{
    const uint16_t a = 0x11bf;   // multiplier of PRNG
    const uint16_t c = 0x4743;   // additive offset of PRNG
    const uint32_t m = 0x10000U; // modulo of PRNG
    uint16_t a_inverse;

    a_inverse = modular_inverse (a, m);

    printf ("a_inverse = %04x\n", a_inverse);

    const uint16_t bx = a; 
    uint16_t dx = 0;
    uint16_t ax = X_0;

    printf ("starting values:    ax=%04x  dx=%04x  bx=%04x\n", ax, dx, bx);
    printf ("forward computation\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
        dx = umul16_hi (ax, bx);
        ax = umul16_lo (ax, bx) + c;
    }
    printf ("after %d iterations: ax=%04x  dx=%04x  bx=%04x\n", ITERS, ax, dx, bx);
    printf ("backward computation\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERS; i++) {
        ax = umul16_lo (ax - c, a_inverse);
    }

    printf ("after %d iterations: ax=%04x\n", ITERS, ax);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```